# Getting a Typescript error saying, some type is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a form for practice and am using `useReducer()` to manage the state. The Typescript error I am getting relates to it, I have tried solving it but no luck.

The full code is available here (Path: src/components/Input.tsx):
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-dew-4uwm3?file=/src/components/Input.tsx)

Full Error:

> TypeScript error in /form/src/components/Input.tsx(47,47):
> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(state: InputState, action: InputAction) => { value: string | undefined; isValid: boolean | undefined; touched: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.  TS2769

```
45 | const Input: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
46 |     console.log(props.required);
47 |     const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
   |                                              
48 |         value: props.initialValue,
49 |         isValid: false,
50 |         touched: false
```

Comment: You're going to have to pass an explicit type parameter to `useReducer`, the compiler can't infer the correct type. https://www.google.com/search?q=typing+reducers+usereducer&oq=typing+reducers+usereducer&aqs=chrome..69i57.9105j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes, I have built an interface and attached it to the inputReducer function: const inputReducer = (state: InputState, action: InputAction) =>... And based on what I have read I do not need to add any thing to the following: const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer...

Answer (score 1):

It's because `InputAction` has properties `value` and `isValid` as optional (they have `?`). That makes `InputAction` equivalent to:

```
interface InputAction {
    value: string | undefined;
    isValid: boolean | undefined;
    touched: boolean;
}
```

which will not relate with `InputState`'s respective properties:

```
interface InputState {
    value: string,
    isValid: boolean,
    touched: boolean
}
```

You can solve this error by either setting `ActionInput`'s respective properties as required (removing `?`) or setting those of `InputState` as optional.

Comment: I do not understand InputAction and InputState are unrelated, I am not extending anything. I do not see how there is a problem. I tried your suggestions but it did not work. You might still correct, so can you elaborate further. Thanks

Comment: This is how I modified https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-rgb-0hq5q?file=/src/components/Input.tsx

Comment: By the way, `InputAction` and `InputState` are actually related when passed to `useReducer`. See the definition here => https://www.sumologic.com/blog/react-hook-typescript/ at "useReducer TypeScript Example"